# How to assign to separate variables with two json arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vuejs2, google-cloud-firestore

This is the json array I got from firestore querySnapshot, and then stored in info variable.

> info = [ { "revitver": [ 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020 ] }, { "categories": [ >"Door", "Window", "Floor", "Wall", "Railing", "Roof", "Pilecap", >"Parapet", "Facade Wall", "Column", "Mechanical", "Electrical", >"Plumbing", "Fire Protection", "Furniture", "Fixtures", "Appliance", >"Ironmongery", "Plant", "Playground", "Vehicle", "Carpark" ] } ]

I intend to store these arrays into separate variables like:
1. datacategories = "Door", "Window", etc...
2. datarevit = 2017, 2018, etc...

This is the code used for getting json arrays from firestore, & pushing to an info variable with array type:

```
        db.collection("familyinfo").get().then(querySnapshot => {
            querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            let data1 = doc.data()
            this.info.push(data1)
```

This is where I want to store the arrays in separate variables:

```
    data: () => ({
        datacategories: [],
        datarevit: [],
        info: [],
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're looking for:

```
db.collection("familyinfo").get().then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
    let data1 = doc.data()
    this.info.push(data1)
    this.datarevit.push(data1.revitver)
    this.datacategories.push(data1.categories)
  })
})
```

I should note that this (getting a property value from an object) is quite basic JavaScript, so I highly recommend looking for a few tutorials.

Comment: Thank you, Frank. I did try to use that but I am getting an array with null value also. Example for revitver = [ [ 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020 ], null ]. We want to get revitver = 2017, 2018, etc. Do you have other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Copying arrays into separate variables seem to solve the problem.

```
        db.collection("familyinfo").get().then(querySnapshot => {
            querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            let data1 = doc.data()
            this.datacategories = [...data1.categories]
            this.datarevit = [...data1.revitver]
```